# Thunderbird installed via Snap on Ubuntu ignores my profile folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thunderbird, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Thunderbid as a snap today (Ubuntu budgie 18.04 LTS). I followed the instructions [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer) to move my profile. This doesn't work. I copied the folder, but nothing is recognized in Thunderbird.

So, I tried:

- Going to 'troubleshoot information' and clicked the button that said "Open Directory". This does not do anything.
- I then ran Thunderbird from the command line, and did the same thing
  again, which shows '`env: ‘/snap/bin/code’: No such file or
  directory` when I tried to open the profile folder. I checked this folder. The folder `/snap/bin` exists and contains a file called 'code' which is a shared lib file, with a target of `/usr/bin/snap`, and has all permissions (`lrwxrwxrwx`). Don't know what to do with that information tough.
- Then I tried importing the files via 'events and tasks --> Import'.
  When I get to the dialog, I can't access my USB, altough permissions
  on it should be sufficient (I ran `chmod 775` on it)
- I tried re-installing Thunderbird, but ended up with the same problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, seems that the bigger problem was not thunderbird being unable to open the profile location (still not working), but me not following the instructions correctly.

What I did:

- Followed the instructions [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data), and ran `thunderbird -ProfileManager` from command line to create a new profile. The manager also showed me the location of the thunderbird profile when installed as a snap on ubuntu: `/home/yourusername/snap/thunderbird/common/.thunderbird/xxxxxxxx.profileName`
- Closed Profile Manager and thunderbird instance
- Replaced the contents of the new profile folder (on the shown location) with the contents of the exported one.
- Started Thunderbird again --> Everything works now!